# Password - uppercase characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Excuse if this is a stupid question. I'm doing a web design subject at uni and am completely stuck. I have to validate a password using Javascript to ensure it has and uppsercase, lowercase, numerical character, and at least 4 characters.

This is the code I have, it's giving me alerts to say I HAVEN'T included the characters, but when I HAVE included them I'm still getting the alert. Any help appreciated.

```
var y = document.forms["loginDetails"]["password"].value;
if (y.length < 4) {
    alert("Your password needs a minimum of four characters")
}
if (y.search[/a-z/i] < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs a lower case letter")
}
if (y.search[/A-Z/i] < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs an uppser case letter")
}
if (y.search[/0-9/] < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs a number")
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I thing that you are missing [] in your regexp. It should be e.g. /[A-Z]/

Comment: I think the issue has been pointed out, but I'll also note that this is an annoying and pointless way to enforce good passwords. At the very least, reduce the number of arbitrary restrictions imposed as the length increases (for example if I want to set `hitheremynameisjohnny`, that's far more secure than `P4ss`)

Comment: Oh and you're searching for an upper/lower case character, but you set the `i` flag, which means ignore case.

Comment: One note with regard to @Dave 's comment: the password should also be validated on the server-side. This code is more for client usability purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Your code had several errors

- comparision should be `<0` not `<1` (`search` returns negative value when regexp is not found)
- `/i` in regexp (case insensitive - not appropriate when trying to figure out upper/lower case characters)
- call of search function was wrong (usage of `[]` instead of `()` )
- in regexp `[]` was missing (`[]` in regexp means one character from given range, so `[a-z]` will match each lowercase character whereas `a-z` will match just string 'a-z')

It should look like:

```
if (y.length < 4) {
  alert("Your password needs a minimum of four characters")
} else if (y.search(/[a-z]/) < 0) {
  alert("Your password needs a lower case letter")
} else if(y.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
  alert("Your password needs an uppser case letter")
} else  if (y.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
  alert("Your password needs a number")
} else {
    // Pass is OK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues with your code:

1. [`String.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns `-1` if the regular expression is not found. Checking against `< 1` will still return `true` incorrectly if the string is found at the `0th` (first) character.
2. `String.search()` is a function and needs to be called with parentheses `(` `)` surrounding the arguments, not brackets `[` `]`.
3. You do not want to perform **case-insensitive** searches in your regular expressions, so remove the `/i` option.
4. Try keeping track of whether or not there was an error in another variable. Then if any of the cases generated an error, you can return `false`.

Try this:

```
var error = false;
var message = '';
if (y.length < 4) {
  message += "Your password needs a minimum of four characters. ";
  error = true;
}
if (y.search(/[a-z]/) == -1) {
  message += "Your password needs at least one lower case letter. ";
  error = true;
}
if (y.search(/[A-Z]/) == -1) {
  message += "Your password needs at least one upper case letter. ";
  error = true;
}
if (y.search (/[0-9]/) == -1) {
  message += "Your password needs a number.";
  error = true;
}
if (error) {
  alert(message);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Pure UX wise, showing 4 alerts if the user doesn't type anything in might be a bit much.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks for your comment. You are correct that multiple alerts is not a good user experience strategy. I have updated my answer to store all messages in one string and then present one alert if there is at least one error.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "search" is a *function*, so you have to call it like y.search(), not with [] brackets (those are used to access a member. y"search" would have the same effect, but search[] is not ok, because it is not an array

Comment: It doesn't need to be an array. You can access properties on function objects as well with square brackets - though it obviously is not wanted here, it is valid syntax :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code this way by:

- Adding `return false;` to each of the failure statement.
- Changing the `search()` function syntax.
- You don't need to use `/i` as it doesn't check the cases.

**Code**

```
var y = document.forms["loginDetails"]["password"].value;
if (y.length < 4) {
    alert("Your password needs a minimum of four characters")
    return false;
}
if (y.search(/[a-z]/) < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs a lower case letter")
    return false;
}
if (y.search(/[A-Z]/) < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs an uppser case letter")
    return false;
}
if (y.search(/[0-9]/) < 1) {
    alert("Your password needs a number")
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The `/i` makes it case insensitive.  If he's checking case specifically, you should remove that...

Comment: @AdamPlocher Thanks for the tip. :) Changed. `:)`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked almost completely, for some reason it is still not recognising when lower case letters have been included and I can't work out why. As I said, please excuse my ignorance I'm completely new to this!

Comment: @k.s Try this: `== -1` instead of `< 1`.

Comment: Fixed using Aiias's suggestion of -1 instead of <1

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is that you're using the 'i' modifier, what tells the regexp to be case insensitive, try without this modifier.

To improve the user experience I use one error message, so, yo could use this code:

```
if(/[a-z]+/.test(s) && /[A-Z]+/.test(s) && /\d+/.test(s) && s.length >= 4)
  return true;

alert("Your password needs Upper and lower case letters, numbers and a minimum four chars");
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var y = document.forms["loginDetails"]["password"].value;

if (y.length < 4) {
    alert("Password should contain minimum four characters");
    return false;
} 

var pwd=/^(?=.*[a-z])/;
var pwd1=/^(?=.*[A-Z])/;
var pwd2=/^(?=.*[0-9])/;

if (pwd.test(y) == false) {
    alert("Password Should contain atleast One lowerCase letter");
    return false;
}

if (pwd1.test(y) == false) {
    alert("Password Should contain atleast One UpperCase letter");
    return false;
}
if (pwd2.test(y) == false) {
    alert("Password Should contain atleast One Number");
    return false;
}
```

Or, you could do the same in a single line as well :

```
var pwd=/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/;
if (pwd.test(y) == false) {
    alert("Password Should contain atleast One Number, One UpperCase and a lowercase letter");   
    return false;
}
```